# Create a copy of an object in flex whose constructor has required parameters

Tags: apache-flex

When using ObjectUtil.copy() on my object, I get the following error

```
Argument count mismatch on foo.bar::MyObject(). Expected 1, got 0.
```

MyObject's constructor takes in one parameter. Is there a way for me to clone, or copy it?

Answer (score 1):

Use the ObjectUtil.[clone](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/utils/ObjectUtil.html#clone%28%29) method.  That should do deep copies.

However, I'm not sure if that will solve the issue.

In Flex 4.5 Neither copy, nor clone, create a new version of the object using the new keyword; therefore the constructor is never called.  Both do byte array copies.  I'd be interested to see your code.

Comment: Here's the code I use. 

var tempObject:MyObject = ObjectUtil.clone(this._myObject) as MyObject;

Comment: And does it work?  Or is that the code giving you an error?  Have you run your code in debug mode to figure out which line is throwing the error?

Comment: This is the exact line that's throwing the error. The error I get is Argument count mismatch on com.foo.bar::MyObject(). Expected 1, got 0.

Comment: @Pasha That is a weird error for that line to throw.  Can you show us the object you're trying to copy?  And/or give us a simple runnable sample demoing the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I use:

```
    public static function clone(source:Object):* {
        var myBA:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
        myBA.writeObject(source);
        myBA.position = 0;
        return(myBA.readObject());
    }
```

Never let me down.

Comment: That is almost identical to the copy method of ObjectUtils, which is what he is using.